# While building OAuth2 client, authCodeGrant using Spring Security, how to intervene in the step when authorization code is exchanged for access-token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, quickbooks-online

I am building a Java Spring Boot OAuth2 client application against Quickbooks, I am using Spring Security's native support for OAuth2 client development ([spring-documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html)) and could able to successfully fetch the access-token and refresh-token as well, thanks to annotation @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient.

The problem is Quickbooks send the account-id (they call it realmId) of the account (and specific company in the account) getting connected to a prospective OAuth2 client app in the OAuth2 step of authorization-code exchange for an access token. On seeing the network calls on developer tools I could see a 302 to http://localhost/8080/?code=<>&state=<>&realmId=<> (as shown in the picture), I need this realmId in my app and I couldn't find a way to grab it.

The OAuth2AuthorizedClient object is giving me the access token and refresh token but no way to reach this previous OAuth2 dance step of authorization code exchange for an access token which I need to have a handle of to get the realmId.

As per Quickbooks there is no API which can be accessed (with or without bearer token) to get the [realmId](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D54R00009jxG2rSAE/is-there-any-api-endpoint-which-i-can-reach-using-the-bearer-token-to-get-realmid), only way is to intervene in between the OAuth2 dance and get it.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to request the "openid" scope when initiating the OAuth2 flow (to get an ID token in addition to access and refresh one)? Is your access token a JWT? If yes, don't claims contain this realmId? If not, have you tried to call the `/userinfo` endpoint on your authorization server?

Comment: So, I have "openid" in scopes, access-token is a JWT but it doesn't have that realmId, and though they do have /userinfo endpoint it doesn't return realmId. 

We can see by their own admission (link below), seems they are happy shipping realmId just with the redirect Uri. https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D54R00009jxG2rSAE/is-there-any-api-endpoint-which-i-can-reach-using-the-bearer-token-to-get-realmid

Comment: That's unfortunate. They could at least offer an API to enrich tokens with such data (like Keycloak "mappers", Auth0 "rules", etc.). As you are configuring a Spring OAuth2 client application, you could still hook in [authorization endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html) to extract this query param you found: `http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> ... )`

Comment: I mean provide a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` which would, for instance, save in session the latest `realmId` value.

Comment: I think some how I have to grab HttpSession object, no luck so far, tinkering with OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver didn't paid much of result as it is all about before initiating the request.

Comment: At least you tried ;) There are answer on stackoverflow for static access to sessions (servlet and reactive). See my answer below, I think it contains all that you need. (Sry, I was busy on another subject)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` saving the `realmId` in session during authorization-code flow:

```java
@Component
static class MyOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultResolver;

    public MyOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        defaultResolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository,
                OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        saveRealmIdInSession(request);
        return defaultResolver.resolve(request);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
        saveRealmIdInSession(request);
        return defaultResolver.resolve(request, clientRegistrationId);
    }

    private void saveRealmIdInSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final var realmIds = request.getParameterValues("realmId");
        if (realmIds.length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        SessionSupport.setAttribute("realmId", realmIds[0]);
    }
}

static class SessionSupport {
    static Optional<HttpSession> getSession() {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes servletAttributes) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(servletAttributes.getRequest()).flatMap(req -> Optional.ofNullable(req.getSession()));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    static Object getAttribute(String name) {
        return getSession().map(session -> session.getAttribute(name)).orElse(null);
    }

    static void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {
        getSession().ifPresent(session -> session.setAttribute(name, value));
    }
}
```

You add it to your security filter-chain configuration as follow:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain clientSecurityFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver)
        throws Exception {
    http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> authorization.authorizationRequestResolver(authorizationRequestResolver)));

    ...

    return http.build();
}
```

All you have to do after that is to read the session to get the `realmId`, accessing it the same way as when it is saved in the `MyOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @ch4mp really appreciate your time.

Meantime, I was re-reading the OAuth2 client-building docs, (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html) and could see that it is the RestTemplate class doing the work of exchanging auth-code for a token, I thought if somehow I can invoke some method of RestTemplate to grab the details of the call to redirect URI but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: If you find another way to access the `realmId`, it would be just fine (but I believe the above works already). The `SessionSupport` should be reusable in this other scenario to persist this `realmId` in session and access it whenever you need

Comment: As of now, I couldn't get your code working, it might be because of gaps in understanding on my side. But after quite some research on this topic and seeing various objects playing their role in grand OAuth2 ACG flow, I couldn't spot the object literally responsible for slicing out the auth-code from the redirect URI call by auth-server, so posted another question (more generic) on this platform. thanks and you have great rest of your day :)

Comment: Have you tried to configure the custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` from above in your client and to set a breakpoint in the `resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId)` method (or in both `resolve` methods) to inspect the request parameters on the `request` during a user OAuth2 login?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help I didn't use your code but found a way to get the 302 redirect-URI (having just the thing am looking for). 
It is the OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient object one needs to customize, which can be done using the default implementation of this interface given by Spring Security (DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient). On second thoughts posting a similar question wasn't needed I guess. Maybe I should delete it? Thanks once again! have a blessed day :)